# Retrieve a Childs Child in Firebase - Unwrap unique-post-ids

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to unwrap data in childs from childs basically. My current database structure looks like this:

```
- user-posts
  - <user-id>
   - user-data
    - <unique-post-id> (As a result from childByAutoId)
      - the data I want to display
    - <unique-post-id> (As a result from childByAutoId)
      - the data I want to display
  ...
 -<user-id>
  -...
 -<user-id>
 ...
```

So as it can be seen, the actual data I want to retrieve is always a child of `<unique-post-id>`, which is automatically generated when the data is written to the database. Retrieving from the database I so far only get:

```
 - <unique-post-id>
 - <unique-post-id>
 - ...
```

Is there a way of unwrapping those and display their childs? What is working for me now is displaying all the unique post id's, but I can't figure out how to get then the child below them, and that for all of them.

The code I'm using to retrieve the data:

```
  func getQuery() -> FIRDatabaseQuery {
        let myTopPostsQuery = (ref.child("user-posts")).child(getUid()).child("user-data")
        return myTopPostsQuery
   }

dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource.init(query: getQuery(),cellReuseIdentifier: "Cellident", view: self.tableView)



dataSource?.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
                        let snap = obj as! FIRDataSnapshot

                        cell.textLabel?.text = snap.key as String
                    }
```

Comment: could you please add the code you are using to retrieve the posts?

Comment: @adolfosrs updated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 dataSource?.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
                    let snap = obj as! FIRDataSnapshot

                    cell.textLabel?.text = snap.key as! String
                    let childString = snap.value as! String
                    // If the child is another dictionary  use `as! [String : AnyObject]`

                }
```

But a different approach might go like this : -

```
  ref.child("user-posts")).child(getUid()).child("user-data").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in

      if snap.exists(){

         for each in snap as! [String : AnyObject] {

              let childString = snap.Value as! String

            }
        }
})
```

Comment: (edit) Thank you so much, the first approach works fine! I am using then this line to write the childs to the text labels:

`let childString = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]

            cell.textLabel?.text = String(childString)`